# Find and replace no longer shows 'replace with'

Tags: replace, find, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Has anyone run into this issue?

I use to be able to right click on the current folder (or Shift + CMD + F) and 'replace with' whatever text. Doesn't seem like it's there anymore.

However, I do see it if I search within the current file.

[image]

Comment: Maybe its caused by the theme, try disabling it temporarily. Which theme are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually ended up being hidden and I had to vertically resize the find/replace section.

http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18554&p=68826#p68826